# [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '10'. This may cause an update error

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios, v-for

I try again and again and I don't understand this error :  [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '10'. This may cause an update error.

I've tried this below but the error occur in my console.

1/ I get a resource from a JSON API to have the user list and the album list
2/ Then I try to merge these array in one 
3/ try to make a v-for loop nested in order to render a list of users with the album of each user per id.

---

My App :

```vue
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- through the users/u array -->
        <div>
            <ul v-for="u in usersInfos" :key="u.id">
                <li class="puce">{{u.name}}</li>
                <li>{{u.username}}</li>
                <li>{{u.email}}</li>
                <li>{{u.phone}}</li>
                <li>{{u.website}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <!-- through the album array / a -->
            <ul ul v-for="album in albums" :key="album.userId">
                <li>{{album.title}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        name: 'Page',
        data() {
            return {
                usersInfos: [],
                usersList: [],
                albums: [],
                search: '',
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            // request users List
            let merge = [];
            let usersList = [];
            let albums = [];

            axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
                .then(response => {
                    this.usersList = response.data
                    usersList = this.usersList;
                    console.log(usersList, 'usersList')
                    merge.push(usersList);
                    console.log(merge, 'FIRST_MERGE')
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });

            axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/albums')
                .then(responseAlbum => {
                    this.albums = responseAlbum.data
                    albums = this.albums;
                    console.log(albums, 'Albums');
                    merge.push(albums);
                    console.log(merge, 'SECOND_MERGE')
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            merge = this.usersInfos;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You most likely have multiple albums with the same `userId`, so `album.userId` as `key` will result in that error.

Comment: Thank you to comment my problem ! Yes, Indeed but I tried many things: album.id, or to put a v-for parent with usersInfos and two v-for children but it doesn't work with no error in the console this time

Comment: Try to output a key in both v-for in an addiotional li element and look for the duplicate

Comment: You can insert the entire .vue file as code, you don't have to split it. You will not lose the code snippets either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably duplicates, if you try to remove the duplicates I think that might do the trick.

Remove duplicates with the code below :

```
this.usersInfos = this.usersInfos.filter((value, index, self) => self.findIndex(m => m.id === value.id) === index)
```